# What does 凸 mean here?

Tags: words, slang, internet-slang

In Yakuza 6, former idol Haruka is looking at an online article about how, as a surrogate daughter of a yakuza, she was spotted in an orphanage in Okinawa.

One of the comments on the article says "だれか凸お願いします♪". I'm wondering what 凸 is supposed to mean here? I have a feeling it's some kind of internet slang.

Here's a picture for context:
[image: picture of comment]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It means *to contact directly*. More specifically, *to make a phone call, make a visit, talk to*. It derives from identifying 突{とつ}撃 and 凸{とつ}.

- [「凸」とは？意味と例文が3秒でわかる！](https://kotowaka.com/internet/totsu/)

---

The usage of 突撃 means an 'attack' in a figurative sense: abruptly being talked to or called by unknown people is considered sort of aggressive. More traditionally, on TV, 突撃レポート means a reporter making unexpected visits to someone or talking to people on the street (supposedly without appointments etc.).

People doing 凸 are sort of paparazzi. It looks like the particular sentence says 'Please someone visit there in person (and tell me what happens)'.

Comment: So ultimately, what is the poster saying? Something like "Can someone DM me?"? It just seems kind of weird/out-of-the-blue.

Comment: @chausies Not sure the context of the message board(?), it could be "DM me*, but I guess it's usually rather *DM him/her*, whoever it is being the topic.  There was a [凸待ち](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ivkBkRUiHqs) (here youtuber awaiting DM), so "DM me" is a possibility if it fits the context.

Comment: I guess this is "Call (or visit) the orphanage directly (and report the conversation here)".

Comment: The dictionary meaning I'm seeing for 突撃 seems very different.

Comment: 凸待ち is a common form of stream for Vtubers (I guess not all of them identify as "virtual") for special events (character birthdays, debut anniversaries, subscriber milestones - though those are more commonly karaoke - etc.). Lacking context, machine translation usually renders this as "convex waiting", which has become something of a meme among viewers. I had been thinking about asking about this 凸 myself.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I added some explanation.